# multiple connectors in kafka to different topics are going to same node

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have created two kafka connectors in kafka-connect which use the same Connector class but have different topics they listen to.

When I launch the process on my node, both the connectors end up creating tasks on this process. However, I would like one node to only handle one connector/topic. How can I limit a topic/connector to a single node? I don't see any configuration in connect-distributed.properties where a process could specify which connector to use.

Thanks

Comment: My vague understanding is that you set them to groups and/or partitions (i'm currently not sure the difference, or which apply to kafka-connect) https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/concepts.html#distributed-workers

Comment: Have you tried standalone mode or using different group.id in the worker configs for the two nodes? This will form two separate connect clusters and force isolation you are describing with the maybe obvious point that you now have two workers to manage separately.

Comment: A task is just a single consumer thread. I'm not understanding the concern

Comment: I have separate group.id in connect-distributed.properties but I'm not sure how do I associate this group.id with the connector created via rest api. Kafka connect is sending both the connectors to same group.id so the other group.id is not getting any tasks. As Robin mention I would like to have separate kafka connect clusters in distributed mode for each topic but can't find any examples or config for it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kafka Connect in distributed mode can run as a cluster of one or more *workers*. Each *worker* can run multiple *tasks*. Depending on how many *connectors* and *workers* you are running, you will have *tasks* running on the same *worker*. This is deliberate - the idea is that Kafka Connect will manage your tasks and workload for you, across the available workers.

If you want to isolate your processing you can run Kafka Connect as separate Connect clusters, either on the same machine (make sure to use different REST ports), or separate machines.

For more info, see [architecture](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/design.html) and [config](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#distributed-mode) for steps to configure separate clusters. Note that a cluster can actually be a single worker, but then you don't have any redundancy in the event of failure.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to achieve. Isolation of the two topics to two different processes/connectors. However, don’t see any documentation besides having separate group.id and some offset, state topics. How does a group Id get associated with a connector name?

Comment: What do you mean, "two topics to two different processes/connectors"? One connector can write to multiple topics (e.g. JDBC can pull multiple tables, and each table goes to its own topic). I think what you're after is this though: you just deploy one connector to one cluster. Each cluster has its own config.

Comment: Can one create multiple kafka connect clusters on one kafka server? How does that get configured?

Comment: See [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#connect-userguide-dist-worker-config) for config. See [here](https://www.confluent.io/whitepaper/confluent-enterprise-reference-architecture/) for a reference architecture. Logically this can all reside on one node. In practice you maybe would separate it out for performance and resilience.

Comment: Even if I give tasks.max=10 for a connector I see only one task been created for the connector. Why is it so. (My cluster configs: 2 brokers, 1 connect worker)

Comment: @D1and1ly start a new question with details of your configuration and deployment.